# Using codeigniter to execute code from another file

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter and I am used to the old school php scripting so I'll need some help with this:

I want to include a Captcha system in one of my forms.
According to its [documentation](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/quickstart-guide/), to generate an image, you need to do it like this:

```
<img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show" alt="CAPTCHA Image" />
```

I downloaded the files, but where do I put them?  And how do I use Codeigniter to call the `securimage_show.php` file?  And output its contents into the `src` attribute of the image?

Comment: @wallyk , your edit has given my question a whole new meaning!! You changed for eg `I am used to the old school php...` to `I am using the old school`... This question is a generic one and not something related to captch. It could be anything! please don't touch my question unless there is something really wrong with it and don't blindly edit something!

Comment: Sorry!  I often edit questions and (answers) to improve the grammar and clarify the meaning.  I apologize for changing the meaning.  It is not something I thought I was doing, and certainly did not intend to change the meaning.

Comment: @wallyk ah, I know. Sorry for being so rude, I didn't mean to rage at you. I Was just annoyed at that moment. Cheers though :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll pay better attention in the future.

Comment: If you are new to the CI, go ahead and download [TA](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) (tank auth, I am pretty sure you are going to use it in future) library, its authorization library and it has captcha implemented in. Inspect library itself + controller 'auth.php' and you'll see how its done with exact example ;)

Answer (score 0):

When adding Captcha in Fuel (a codeigniter based cms), I've put the php file that generates the Captcha image in the folder where you put images, then link to it the same way you link to an image:

```
<?php echo img(array('src'=>'image_show.php', 'alt'=> 'CAPTCHA Image')); ?>
```

Perhaps not the nicest solution, but it works.

Alternatively, just use a Captcha plugin written specifically for codeigniter, such as the NuCaptcha CodeIgniter plugin, http://docs.nucaptcha.com/plugins/codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigiter have a captcha [helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html).

First, you want to create a folder where you will be able to store your captcha images and give this folder permissions to perform read/write operations. In this case, I've created `captcha` folder in root of my codeigniter instance.

Then, we want to load `captcha` helper:

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
```

Let's initiate instance of captcha with our settings (you can do it either in `Controller` or `View` with your form):

```
$rand_string = strtoupper(random_string('nozero', 4));
$settings = array(
    'word' => $rand_string,
    'img_path'   => './captcha/',
    'img_url'    => base_url() .'captcha/',
    'img_width'  => '250',
    'img_height' => 35,
     'expiration' => 7200
);

$cap = create_captcha($settings);
$this->session->set_userdata('captchaWord',$cap['word']);
```

Please note, that I'm keeping generated captcha word in my `session` whenever I create it (for instance on page refresh). This way I can compare original `captcha word` with input from my `form`. Then, I will display generated captcha image with input field somewhere in my form (View):

```
<form id="my_form">
   <input type="text" name="captcha" value=""/>
   <?= $cap['image']; ?>
</form>
```

Now, all I have to do, is to compare `input` received from `my_form` with actual captcha value (in my controller, where I handle form submission):

```
$userCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
$actual_word = $this->session->userdata('captchaWord');
if( strcmp(strtoupper($userCaptcha),strtoupper($actual_word)) == 0  ) {
  // input and captcha are the same
}
```